# Issue redirecting 404 error in mvc to NotFound page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

Am trying to implement error page in my mvc application using **ELMAH**.

Error logging works perfectly.But in case of `404 NotFound`  method in my controller is not getting called

**web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="Error" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

**Error Controller**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
public ActionResult Error()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult NotFound()
 {
 return View();
 }
 }
```

The below scenario with URL

`http://localhost/Error/sfdsfdf` ==> Works correctly and redirects to 404 page

but in case if i give

```
http://localhost/something
```

Am getting Runtime error and my URL is

```
http://localhost:61553/Error?aspxerrorpath=/something
```

I understand it is an error while redirecting but am not sure what i am missing.

Am trying not to use NotFound Nugget !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should also add in your `web.config` the error code `400` - Bad Request and `403` - Forbidden

```
    <customErrors mode="On">
          <error statusCode="500" redirect="Error" />
          <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
          <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: Does it make any difference or answer my question ?

Comment: Yes - I think the error you get is possibly 403 - and it is not being redirected because you don't capture in in your web.config